# How to change the layouts of the PowerApps-customized SharePoint form?

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, powerapp

I've customized a SharePoint list form using PowerApps and I don't see an option anywhere that would allow me to make the app large or responsive. So far PowerApps-customized forms look like a joke. Does anyone know if there is a way to "stretch" this form?

I know, that Microsoft might think that it's so small because it's "mobile first". But the thing is that PowerApps-customized forms don't show in SharePoint mobile apps anyway. So what's the point of these PowerApps being so slim? Can someone, please comment on it?

[image]

**Update**

Please, note that the original question was asked in 2018 when the setting for resizing didn't yet exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just like any other Power App, form apps have a setting for resizing:

In your App, navigate to **Settings** > **Screen size + orientation** > **Size**

[image]

**Limitations**

[image]

Comment: "Resizing is now possible with limitations". Q: *HOW*?  And *what* limitations?

Comment: @FoggyDay. thanks for the feedback. updated the answer.

Comment: Beautiful - thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

There's actually a real easy way to increase the width on Powerapps forms that are integrated with sharepoint lists, so that not only is the empty whitespace utilized on the NewForm.aspx page, but on the list view itself if they click '+ New' that the pane will extend out further. Open the powerapps form you want to customize first, and then:

1. Click on File (top left hand side)
2. Click on App Settings
3. Click on Screen size + Orientation.
4. Then select the Orientation you want (Portrait or Landscape) and whether you want it small or large.
5. Make sure you click on Apply in the bottom right of the screen (it
   doesn’t really jump out at you).

Pick the landscape option, and then go back to your form and you'll be able to drag the fields out to the new wider width, then just save and publish.

Answer (score 1):

The modern SharePoint lists are built using React framework I believe. This way the form loads without a page reload happening. The forms loads within a Canvas which is on the same page(List). Even I couldn't find a way of resizing this canvas.
An app created here could be resized but possibly not the list form.

Comment: The question was about a PowerApps-customized item forms, not about the modern lists or classic PowerApps. I see that there is no "Width" property available in PowerApps for the screen. The only way to override it would be a terrible hack by using SPFx application customizer that will change the widths of multiple elements, including elements inside an iFrame (because PowerApps item form is loaded in an iframe)

Answer (score 0):

Per my test in my SharePoint online environment, I customize the list from in PowerApps. When I create new item or edit the item, there is no such white space in the form.
 [image]

To troubleshoot the issue, you could check things below:

1. Clear IE cache.
2. Switch to other browser to check if the same issue will occur.

Using PowerApps to customize the list form is the new feature. And it will be improved in the future.

There is a workaround.

You could customize the list form in InfoPath.

Per my test in my SharePoint online environment, by default it will not open a new tab when I create a new item or edit the item.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, Amy. Try clicking on the "Copy link" button and open it in the new tab. This way you can reproduce what I am talking about.

Comment: I have updated my answer.

Comment: Since the form is by default a NewForm.aspx, instead of clicking on the list view of + New, change the URL when you're viewing the list from what's most likely 'AllItems.aspx' to 'NewForm.aspx' to see what he's talking about. That same restricted pane that pops out from the right side of the screen when you click + New is being replicated on the full page.